# SO Chat user profile page broke!

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I can't access the chat user profile page on SO chat... What is wrong?

It redirects me to an error page... Is this some maintenance issue?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I reproduce that.

Comment: it is back now... what happened?

Comment: I reproduce the "back now" too. This question shall probably be deleted.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268293/https-urls-dont-work-in-chat-previews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad; a side effect of [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268293/https-urls-dont-work-in-chat-previews/268295#268295) - now resolved.